# compilation order and post prefix opertors

Tags: perl, printf, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

I was wondering why the following outputs `7 7 6 7` instead of `5 6 6 7`

```
my $a = 5;
printf("%d %d %d %d",$a,++$a , $a++ , $a);
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the order of parameters compilation

Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before I start, let me point out that one should generally avoid situations where one you both sets and reads a variable within an expression.

---

First, let's look at operand evaluation order. This isn't defined for many operators, but it is defined for the list operator. It's documented to evaluate its operands in left-to-right order<sup>[1]</sup>. That means that `printf`'s arguments are evaluated in the following order:

1. `"%d %d %d %d"`
2. `$a`
3. `++$a`
4. `$a++`
5. `$a`

The key lies in knowing that `$a` doesn't place a copy of the value of `$a` on the stack. It places the scalar itself (a `SV*`, in C terms). In Perl jargon, we say the stack element is *aliased* to `$a`<sup>[2]</sup>. In computing theory, you'd say the arguments are passed *by reference*.

And the same goes for `++$a`, but `$a++` necessarily places a copy of `$a` on the stack.

This means we can view the above `printf` call as equivalent to

```
use Data::Alias qw( alias );

{
    local @_;
    alias $_[0] = "%d %d %d %d";
    alias $_[1] = $a;    # Places $a on the stack.
    alias $_[2] = ++$a;  # Adds one to $a and places $a on the stack.
    alias $_[3] = $a++;  # Places a copy of $a on the stack and adds one to $a.
    alias $_[4] = $a;    # Places $a on the stack.
    &CORE::printf;
 }
```

By the time `$a++` is called, `$a` contains 6.

By the time `printf` is called, `$a` contains 7.

---

The workaround is to make copies of the values.

```
$ perl -le'$a = 5; my @b = ($a, ++$a, $a++, $a); print "@b";'
7 7 6 7

$ perl -le'$a = 5; my @b = (0+$a, 0+(++$a), $a++, $a); print "@b";'
5 6 6 7
```

---

1. From [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html), "In list context, it's just the list argument separator, and inserts both its arguments into the list. These arguments are also evaluated from left to right."
2. From [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html), "Any arguments passed in show up in the array `@_`. Therefore, if you called a function with two arguments, those would be stored in `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`. The array `@_` is a local array, but its elements are aliases for the actual scalar parameters."

Comment: (Well, you can't do `&CORE::printf` yet, but you get the idea.)

Comment: thanks! so basically that's because printf uses aliases rather then shifting each value?

Comment: Every sub call uses aliasing, so it doesn't matter whether `printf` "shifts values" or not. By the time `printf` is called, `$a` already contains `7`. Replace `printf` with your own sub if you want to experiment.

Comment: @soulSurfer2010 It's not even about subs only: the same happens with assignment, for example. Check `@b` after `my @b = ($a, ++$a, $a++, $a);`, it's 7767 too. )