# Strange behavior of regex matches in list

Tags: perl

I have experienced strange behavior of using Regex captures for assignment of list elements - which puzzles me a lot, and I could not find an explanation anywhere in the documentation and other places. The code that I use is like this:

```
$_ = "one 1 two 2 three 3";
my $n = 1;
my @tt = (
    /one (\S+)/ ? (one => $1) : (),
    /two (\S+)/ ? (two => $1) : (),
    /three (\S+)/ ? (three => $1) : (),
);
print "Array: " . join(" ", @tt) . "\n";
```

Which prints, surprisingly:

```
Array: one 3 two 3 three 3
```

while I expect that it will print:

```
Array: one 1 two 2 three 3
```

So, when I use `//` and `?:` within a list assignment, I always get captures from the last(!) matching expression - be it `$1` or `$&` or anything else that refers to captures.

When I surround each `?:` with `do {}`, everything works as expected, though.

My question is - what I am doing wrong? Is it a bug or some well known (or hidden) feature/behavior that I am not aware of?

Thank you!

PS: If this matters - I use standard perl 5.22.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.2, though the behavior is the same on Perl 5.8.8 and 5.24.1

EDIT: Though the reason for this behavior is the same as in this question -
 [compilation order and post prefix opertors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570415/compilation-order-and-post-prefix-opertors) - but the context is quite different and it is not immediately obvious that questions are similar, as the previous question is about passing arguments to a sub, while in my question no subs are involved.

Comment: To be honest, I doubt so - using () around every ternary operator, like "(/one (\S+)/ ? (one => $1) : ())" does not change a thing - it still takes the last expression...

Comment: the same underlying cause does not make this a duplicate question

Comment: But the fact that the answer is the same does, according to history. Closing a question doesn't prevent it from being found in searches; it prevents duplicate answers.

Comment: @aldem, The other answer mentions that no subs are involved, giving `my @b = ($a, ++$a, $a++, $a);` as an example.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, Done.

Comment: @ikegami I see your reasoning, though the other question may not be of immediate help for someone who is looking for similar issue. While I was searching for a cause, I knew that it was definitely not related to compilation/evaluation order nor post/infix operators - so I simply could not find it. Anyway, as long as the question is searchable, I hope it will be helpful to someone.

Comment: @aldem, I've already added the missing bits to the other answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to [compilation order and post prefix opertors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570415/compilation-order-and-post-prefix-opertors) also answers your question. What follows is a summary.

---

Generally speaking, avoid situations where you both set and read a variable within an expression<sup>[1]</sup>.

Your code does the following:

1. You set `$1`.
2. You place a string and `$1` on the stack. (Not a copy of `$1`!)
3. You set `$1`.
4. You place a string and `$1` on the stack.
5. You set `$1`.
6. You place a string and `$1` on the stack.
7. You copy the contents of the stack (string, `$1`, string, `$1`, string, `$1`) into `@tt`. `$1` is `3` at this point.

You can work around this by using `"$1"` instead of `$1`, since `"$1"` builds a new string from `$1`.

---

1. That said, `my $x = /(foo|bar)/ ? $1 : 'default';` would not have given you any problems.

Comment: Thank you - that was it! How could I forget that I am dealing with a reference here... :(

Comment: Could you not just do `my @tt =  /(one|two|three) (\S+)/;` ?

Comment: @Mark Reed, Maybe. The output would be different for `three 3 two 2 one 1`.

Comment: @MarkReed Not really - one reason is mentioned by ikegami and my reason is that real code is a bit more complicated, like `my @tt = (/one (\S)/ ? foo($1) : "", /two (\S)/ ? bar($1) : "")`.

Comment: @aldem, If that's your code, you shouldn't have had any problems.

Comment: @ikegami Well, it was even _more_ complicated :) In some cases there were function calls, but in some just expressions referring to $1 directly - that's why it puzzled me a lot - part of values were OK, while others were duplicates of the last one, so I reduced my sample to fragments which actually produced wrong results.